# How to handle Memory Leak in BackgroundWorker DoWork eventhandler

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, datagridview, backgroundworker

I'm creating an application(logviewer) which will display the logs from xml files. Note: each xml file can have one or more records.my application has to show each record as one row in DatagridView control.

basically it will perform the following tasks:

1.from the Do_Work => parse each xml file and add the records to the List.
2.if the List size reaches 100 then call the ProgressChanged event to update the UI (DataGridView) with 100 records.
3.repeat this process untill all records from all xml files are appended to the UI (DataGridView)

**Implementation:**

DoWork will add each record to original list and once if the list count becomes 100 it creates a new List Collection and call the ProgressChanged event.

as below:

```
bWorkerReadXmlLogs.ReportProgress(0, new List<XmlLogRecord>(lstXmlLogRecords)); //memory leak
```

now ProgressChanged event handler will append the 100 records to the DataGridView.

but if i run application with some thousands of xml files it is taking huge memory and not releasing at all.
see pic below:(application started with 3,000K)

[image]

but if i just pass the original collection reference variable as below - it works :

```
bWorkerReadXmlLogs.ReportProgress(0, lstXmlLogRecords); //it works
```

but the problem is by the time `ProgressChanged` event handler appends all 100 records into `DataGridView` Control, `DoWork`(as there is no synchronization between DoWork and ProgressChanged events) clears it(Original Collection) to add another set of records and `ProgressChanged` throws collection modified exception.

now i need to know howto release the memory by copying/creating a new collection from original collection:

**My Analysis:**
I can pass orginal collection reference variable and wait for more time in `DoWork` Background thread to make sure that Main/UI Thread adds all 100 records to DataGridView but it is not optimal solution and if user runs application in some low end configuration it may not be sure that it works always.

Sample Code:

```
private void bWorkerReadXmlLogs_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {                               
        //declare a xmlLogRecords list to hold the list of log records to be displayed on the UI
        List<XmlLogRecord> lstXmlLogRecords = new List<XmlLogRecord>();

        //loop through the records sent by the GetLogDetails() function and add it to the list
        foreach (XmlLogRecord record in GetLogDetails(path))
        {
            //cancel the background thread if the cancel was requested from the user.
            if (bWorkerReadXmlLogs.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            //add log record to the list
            lstXmlLogRecords.Add(record);

            /*if the list contains 100 items then invoke the progresschanged event 
            where it appends the 100 items into the LogViewer UI (DataGridView)*/
            if (lstXmlLogRecords.Count % 100 == 0)
            {
                //block/wait on background thread so that processor allocates some cycles to work on UI/Main thread to update the records on the DatagridView
                Thread.Sleep(200); 


                bWorkerReadXmlLogs.ReportProgress(0, new List<XmlLogRecord>(lstXmlLogRecords));//Memory Leak here,if i pass original collection reference it works but DoWork clears it immediatly to add new set of records

                //clear the List to start/add remaining items.
                lstXmlLogRecords.Clear();
            }
        }

        //invoke the ProgressChanged Event for updating the DataGridView if the List contains less than 100 items greater than 0 items
        if (lstXmlLogRecords.Count > 0)
        {                
            //Invoke ProgressChanged Event to update the records on the DataGridView
            bWorkerReadXmlLogs.ReportProgress(0, lstXmlLogRecords);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Write_Trace(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void bWorkerReadXmlLogs_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{           
        try
        {
            var rowIndex = 0;
            if (e.UserState is List<XmlLogRecord>)
            {
                //Cast the UserState object into the List<XmlLogRecord>
                var records = e.UserState as List<XmlLogRecord>;

                //iterate over all the records sent from DoWork event and append the each record into the LogViewer control DataGridView UI
                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    //get the next row Index where the new row has to be placed.
                    rowIndex = dgvLogViewer.Rows.Count;

                    //add an emtpy row to add the empty cells into it
                    dgvLogViewer.Rows.Add();

                    //set the LogViewer properties if not set already
                    if (!IsLogviewerPropertiesSet)
                    {
                        SetLogViewerProperties();
                    }

                    //Disable the Column selection for image columns
                    DisableImageColumnsSelection(rowIndex);

                    //Add Data for normal or text cells into the LogViewer Control (DatagridView)
                    AddLogviewerTextCells(rowIndex, record);

                    //Add Icons in Image Columns into the LogViewer control (DataGridView) 
                    AddLogviewerImageCells(rowIndex, record);
                }

                //Sort the LogViewer control (DataGridView) by Datetime column(Index = 2) in Descending order.
                dgvLogViewer.Sort(dgvLogViewer.Columns[MKeys.DTTIME], ListSortDirection.Descending);
                dgvLogViewer.Columns[MKeys.DTTIME].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
                if (!IsLogviewerSortingDone)
                {
                    //call selectedindex changed event of the selected record in the datagridview
                    dgvLogViewer_SelectionChanged(null, null);
                    IsLogviewerSortingDone = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                   
            Write_Trace(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter : please let me know if anything wrong with my post so that i can take care.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: `.NET Framework 2.0`

Comment: If you're going to parse thousands of XMLs into a datagrid, those strings are going to consume memory as they're kept alive by your datagrid.

Comment: At the time of the memory snap taken how many number of rows your `DataGridView` contains? I don't see a memory leak. All I see is only memory usage, and that's it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: at the time of snap taken 4,000 rows added to DataGridView twice.as DataGridView cleared first 4,000 records and added again but memory is getting consumed from previous usage(because memory is not reducing even if i clear DataGridView).

Comment: May be the matter of GarbageCollection I guess. For testing purpose add a button and on click of it call `GC.Collect` and see what is the memory usage. If memory comes down, you don't have to worry. GC will take care when it is supposed to. If still memory consumption is high you need a memory profiler to see what is consuming memory.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Thank you, Okay let me check.

Comment: couldn't it be the garbage collector that is waiting its clean cycle? 300000k isn't that much memory when a application is actively processing large amounts of data to be honest. My personal guess would be that the clean cycle of the garbage collector is pending to save out cpu power as there is no low memory warnings. You could enforce it with a GC.Collect But unless your application is starting to use gigs of memory I would just leave it be.